# Flutte xcode build failed after upgrading flutter

Tags: flutter

my app was working nicely and I upgraded my flutter to `Flutter 1.20.2 and Dart 2.9.1`. Now if I run my flutter project I get a big error message.

Bellow is the error.

```
            Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
        Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                        
        Xcode build done.                                           14.5s
        Failed to build iOS app
        Error output from Xcode build:
        ↳
            ** BUILD FAILED **


        Xcode's output:
        ↳
            12 warnings generated.
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-2.2.0+1/ios/Classes/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:99:11: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'BOOL *' (aka 'bool *') with an expression of type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool')
            [-Wint-conversion]
                BOOL *value = [[FIRMessaging messaging] isAutoInitEnabled];
                    ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-2.2.0+1/ios/Classes/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:174:75: warning: 'token' is deprecated: Use instanceIDWithHandler: instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            [_channel invokeMethod:@"onToken" arguments:[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]];
                                                                                    ^
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-2.2.0+1/ios/Classes/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:7:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:46:
            In file included from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.h:17:
            /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseInstanceID/FIRInstanceID.h:217:30: note: 'token' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
            - (nullable NSString *)token __deprecated_msg("Use instanceIDWithHandler: instead.");
                                        ^
            In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h:17:
            In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
            In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.2.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:191:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
                    #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                                ^
            2 warnings generated.
            lib/screens/eventDetailsScreen/eventDetails.dart:90:28: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
            Try removing the extra positional arguments.
                pr = new ProgressDialog(context, ProgressDialogType.Normal);
                                    ^
            ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/progress_dialog-1.2.4/lib/progress_dialog.dart:40:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
            ProgressDialog(BuildContext context,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            lib/screens/eventDetailsScreen/eventDetails.dart:91:8: Error: The method 'setMessage' isn't defined for the class 'ProgressDialog'.
            - 'ProgressDialog' is from 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart' ('../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/progress_dialog-1.2.4/lib/progress_dialog.dart').
            Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMessage'.
                pr.setMessage(FlutterI18n.translate(context, "Please wait"));
                ^^^^^^^^^^

            Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
            note: Using new build system
            note: Planning build
            note: Constructing build description
            warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
            warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
            warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
            warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
            warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
            warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
            warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')

        Could not build the application for the simulator.
        Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hkm Sadek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7184947/hkm-sadek) I had this same problem recently, the solution I got was to update some dependencies in the project.

Delete these files Podfile, Podfile.lock, pubspec.lock:

```
rm ios/podfile
rm ios/podfile.lock
rm pubspec.lock
```

Finally delete also `Pods` folder and execute these commands:

```
flutter clean
pod init
pod install
```

Run again

Comment: If I run `pod init` it says `[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one
`

Comment: Make sure you're in your project ios folder

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.
The answer from Hakiza fixed it but only for a couple of days. No project clean, no pod reset and NO REBOOT ;) fixed it.
Since flutter 1.20.2 is relatively new and there are a lot of issues regarding Xcode buid issues we downgraded our version.

```
flutter downgrade
rm -rf ios/Pods
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Comment: Faced the same issue. XCode build was failing - even without a decent error message. Nothing helped (not even recreating the ios folder). Eventually tried the downgrade from 1.20.2 to 1.20.1 (+ cleaning pods + flutter pub get). Then it finally worked again.